# How much does overlapping the four spheres of Dancing Darkness reduce the light level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, vision-and-light

I see some ambiguity with the spell [Dancing Darkness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dancing-darkness). What is the consensus on the following?

I take the usage of *each* in this rule to mean that the light reduction comes from all four orbs.

> You create either up to four spheres of darkness that each reduce the illumination level by one step within a 20-foot-radius

This would mean that in an area on which all four radii overlap the light level would be reduced 4 levels.

The restriction on the relative position of each sphere may make this overlapping difficult to control, which I feel was intended because of this stacking of the orbs. With fine light level control coming from the fact that is *up to four* spheres. You could choose how many to change the light level from −1 to −4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a pretext, I'd like to list the light levels used in Pathfinder:

- Bright Light
- Normal Light
- Dim Light
- Darkness
- Deeper Darkness

On Deeper Darkness, it cannot be reached unless an effect specifically calls for it. So for spells that don't, reducing the light by 4 levels would take you from any light to Darkness.

However, that doesn't answer this question.

### Dancing Darkness is actually not that powerful, being a first level spell

Light (and Darkness) spell are weighted against *ambient* light first, then each other if they coexist. From the [FAQ for Light and Darkness effects](http://paizo.com/paizo/blog/v5748dyo5lhfm?Illuminating-Darkness):

> Darkness spells first negate nonmagical light sources like lanterns and sunrods, and then they tell you **how many steps to reduce the "ambient" light**

Emphasis mine. What this means is that ***each* orb of Dancing Darkness is weighed against ambient light, not each others'** already reduced light. You could create a square-is shape 30x30ft of 1 less level, or a 20x50 length of -1 light level, but the central pieces would be just as dark as the edges.